# Pycharm plugin for autocompletion in Django

Tags: django, pycharm

I am learning Django for a couple of month now and I've noticed that there's  some methods/fields and stuff like that (e.g. get_absolute_url), that Pycharm doesn't offer autocomplition for. So I've been wondering are there any plugins or something for pycharm i can install to make autocomplition more thorough?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of PyCharm are you using ? Community or Professional ?

Comment: @May.D Hello! I am using community version.

Comment: Django autocompletion is included in Professional edition, I don't think you will find a workaround in Community version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to configure Pycharm for Django, but that feature is available only for Pycharm Professional. Btw there are great free plugins for Djnago and Python in Visual Studio Code.